# How can I upload fresh code at github?

Tags: git, github

I have a directory with all my coding projects.

I want to upload (correct terminology?) it to [GitHub](http://github.com) using the command line.

I have already looked at [Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/).

I know how to clone an existing project, and how to push it after making any changes.

But in this case, I want to make a new project and add files to that.

How can I accomplish this using the command line?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

After this, make a new GitHub repository and follow on-screen instructions.

Comment: So, the repository willbe created using GitHub gui only, not through command line?

Comment: @eSKay: you'll first have to have a local repo, then add a remote to it, and push to that remote. All of this is done from the command line. Pushing to github has some pre-requisites, such as creating a project on github and adding ssh keys to identify yourself.

Comment: This didn't work. I get the following error message for the git push -u origin master : "error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxx/yyyy.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details."

Comment: I guess this problem results because github created a README.md in its repository. The problem was solved with the instruction 'git pull -u origin master'. This merged the github repository into my local one. Then I could upload the new version with 'git push -u origin master'

Comment: This answer leaves out too much information for a beginner's "How do it commit in GitHub?" question.

Answer (score 28):

If you haven't already created the project in Github, do so on that site. If memory serves, they display a page that tells you exactly how to get your existing code into your new repository. At the risk of oversimplification, though, you'd follow Veeti's instructions, then:

```
git remote add [name to use for remote] [private URI] # associate your local repository to the remote
git push [name of remote] master # push your repository to the remote
```

Comment: I recommend to first do a `pull`, if the user created a ReadMe for their repository, otherwise they will have to do a merge.

Comment: Nope, just created a repo and it gives **absolutely no** instructions on what to do next

Comment: @puk Not sure where you are or what you're seeing, but when I create a new repo on Github, I see a very clear set of instructions. 1 set to "Create a new repository on the command line", another to "Push an existing repository from the command line" and yet another for using the Github desktop application.

Answer (score 22):

Just to add on to the other answers, before i knew my way around git, i was looking for some way to upload **existing code** to a new github (or other git) repo. Here's the brief that would save time for newbs:-

Assuming you have your NEW empty github or other git repo ready:-

```
cd "/your/repo/dir"
git clone https://github.com/user_AKA_you/repoName # (creates /your/repo/dir/repoName)
cp "/all/your/existing/code/*" "/your/repo/dir/repoName/"
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

Alternatively if you have an existing local git repo

```
cd "/your/repo/dir/repoName"
#add your remote github or other git repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user_AKA_you/your_repoName
git commit -m "new origin commit"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create GitHub repositories via the command line using their Repositories API (<s>http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html</s>)

Check [Creating github repositories with command line | Do it yourself Android](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/creating_github_repositories_with_command_line_do.html) for example usage.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Github has changed their layout since you posted this question. I just created a repository and it used to give you instructions on screen. It appears they have changed that approach.

Here is the information they used to give on repo creation:

[Create A Repo · GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux use below command to upload code in git 

1 ) git clone repository
  ask for user name and password.
2) got to respositiory directory.
3) git add  project name.
4) git commit -m ' messgage '.
5) git push origin master.
- user name ,password

Update new Change code into Github

->Goto  Directory That your github up code
->git commit ProjectName -m 'Message'
->git push origin master.

Answer (score 0):

From [Github guide: Getting your project to Github](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/):(using Github desktop version)

> Set up your project in GitHub Desktop
>
> The easiest way to get your project into GitHub Desktop is to drag the
>   folder which contains your project files onto the main application
>   screen.
>
> If you are dragging in an existing Git repository, you can skip ahead
>   and push your code to GitHub.com.
>
> If the folder isn’t a Git repository yet, GitHub Desktop will prompt
>   you to turn it into a repository. Turning your project into a Git
>   repository won’t delete or ruin the files in your folder—it will
>   simply create some hidden files that allow Git to do its magic.

[image]

In Windows it looks like this:(GitHub desktop 3.0.5.2)

[image]

this is not the most geeky way but it works.