# How do I deploy an Azure Website while using GitHub as source control?

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a website and use GitHub for source control. How can I have Azure websites point to my GitHub account and pull the code from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure App Service supports continuous deployment to Web Apps from source code control and repository tools like BitBucket, CodePlex, Dropbox, Git, GitHub, Mercurial, and TFS. You can use these tools to maintain the content and code for your application, and then quickly and easily push changes to your Azure web app when you want.

There are a several steps to make this happen:

1. [Create an empty website on Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/04/08/build-your-own-web-site-using-azure-for-free-in-5-minutes.aspx).
   [image]
2. [Push your web code from your local Git repository to one on GitHub.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866872/how-can-i-upload-fresh-code-at-github)
3. From with in the Azure portal, click on your newly created website, followed by **Deployments** -> **Set up continuous deployment**.
   [image]
4. At the next screen, you'll be prompted to select your source. Select **GitHub**.
   [image]
5. You'll be prompted to enter your credentials.
6. Select the repository you'd like to monitor, and if possible, the **branch**.
   [image]

In a few moments Azure will pull the code from your GitHub repository, and you'll be good to go!

You are not limited to GitHub, though. You can also deploy from BitBucket, CodePlex, Dropbox, GitHub, or Mercurial results in a continuous deployment process where Azure will pull in the most recent updates from your project, nearly instantly.

Comment: Looks like Github can't be used with template deployment though.

Comment: I believe it still can. I deployed several Project Nami projects today from GitHub today using this: 

https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami