# How do I set GitHub as my deployment source for an Azure AppService?

Tags: github, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to set GitHub as my source for my Azure AppService deployment. I have gone to Deployment | Deployment Center. I fill it out and press save (workflows configuration edit box I left blank as I don't know what that is).

But when I try to go elsewhere in the portal, I get: "Your unsaved edits will be discarded."

**What do I need to do?**

**ps -** [This answer is obsolete.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490796/how-do-i-deploy-an-azure-website-while-using-github-as-source-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to set GitHub as my source for my Azure AppService
> deployment

### To set GitHub as your source for azure App service you can follow the below workaround :

- Create an empty **webapp** on Azure
- From Deployment center> select source(GitHub)> **Authorize**>select your repository& branch.

[image]

[image]

- As above marked Workflow configuration is something that we have added our repository and runtime stack etc . We can see it by click on Preview file as below:

It will something like this:

[image]

- Save it and after few moment Azure will pull the code from your repository .

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Continuous deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github) .